# Heroku: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app deployed in heroku that uses postgresql as database. I have created a new model that will connect to a remote mysql database like the following:

```
# other_database.rb(apps/models/)
class OtherDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "remote_#{Rails.env}"
end

# other_model.rb(apps/models/)
class OtherModel < OtherDatabase
  self.table_name = "users"
end
```

i have also edited the database.yml file and added these entries:

```
remote_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

remote_production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: app_production
  pool: 40
  username: root
  password: secretpassword
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: 12.34.56.78
```

The remote database uses mysql as its database.

It works fine in my local machine, but when I deploy it to heroku, it creates an error page so I looked up on the heroku logs, and I found this one out:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:52:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
```

I am spent almost all my time searching for some answers but to no avail. Hope anyone can help out with this issue.

TIA.

Eralph

Answer (score 3):

Heroku deletes and recreates the database.yml file. This means that what ever you put in your database.yml file will be totally ignored by heroku.

Pop your db credentials in your establish_connection method call like so:

```
establish_connection(
  adapter: 'mysql2',
  encoding: 'utf8',
  reconnect: true,
  database: 'app_production',
  pool: 40,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'secretpassword',
  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
  host: '12.34.56.78'
)
```

However it would be better to use a database URL and store it in an environment variable in heroku.

```
heroku config:set MYSQL_DB_URL=http://example.com/rest_of_the_url
```

then use

```
establish_connection(ENV['MYSQL_DB_URL'])
```

Example and docs for a url can be found here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,10734,10750

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How do you set the username and password, and also the database name using the environment variable link?

Comment: heroku config:set DB_USERNAME=username DB_PASSWORD=password then reference them via ENV['DB_USERNAME'] and ENV['DB_PASSWORD']

Comment: I will give this a try and will let you know if something comes up. Thanks.